# Vagrant guest's /var/www freezes when doing config.vm.synced

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vagrant

I reviewed all synced_folder configuration @ Vagrant's website...

Host OS: Windows 7
Guest OS: Ubuntu

this is my Vagrantfile config:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|  
    config.vm.box = "base"
    config.vm.hostname = "daison.vagrant.me"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    #config.vm.synced_folder "C:\\Users\\daison\\vagrant\\src\\www", "/var/www"
end
```

I also do `C:\Users\daison\vagrant\> vagrant reload`

I can access my the Ubuntu's apache, by running `127.0.0.1:8080 or 192.168.33.10 or daison.vagrant.me:8080` -- **IN MY HOST**

so by removing the `commented synced_folder` and reloading again the vagrant. The results of all the IP ADDRESSES AND MY VIRTUALHOST ARE **NOT ACCESSIBLE** -- **INT MY HOST**

I tried accessing `vagrant ssh`

```
vagrant@daison: cd /var/www
vagrant@daison: /var/www$ ls
```

and nothing showing up...

I also tried to create a `folder` just to see if the synced_folder really works even if it freezes the guest folder

```
vagrant@daison: /var/www$ mkdir thisFolderWillAlsoShareToHost
```

Then a folder in my `C:\Users\daison\vagrant\src\www` created **IN MY HOST**.

---

I also tried to change the synced_folders to `"/vagrant/sample"` just to test if `/vagrant/sample` will be freeze the same with `/var/www`, after reloading the vagrant.

The result is; I can access the web-server, ofcourse it is not part in `/var/www`, but using `ls` inside `/vagrant/sample` freezes also.

Maybe someone could help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest are buggy or too different version with the VirtualBox version in your host. Try upgrading them. The [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin can do it automatically.

As downloading and installing the Guest Additions takes time, you might want to [package the updated box](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html), or build your box yourself using e.g. [packer](http://packer.io/).